# Multiple updates in one document using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update multiple values in a single document in one mongoose call.  Is this possible?

I have something similar to this:

```
update = {$inc : { numShown : 1 }, $inc : { secondField.subField : 1 }};
options = {};
MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req._id, update, options, function(err){
     if(err){ return console.error(err);}
}
```

It runs, but doesn't update anything.

Comment: An object can't contain two of the same keys, have you tried passing it as an array? `update = [{ $inc : { numShown : 1 }},  { $inc : { secondField.subField : 1 }}];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine the two `$inc` values into a single object and quote the dotted key:

```
update = { $inc : { numShown : 1, 'secondField.subField' : 1 } };
```

Comment: perfect, I also forgot to specify the collection name in my mongoose model, which created an extra collection with no documents.  I wish there were a simple way to search the database rather than the collections by id, since they should be unique.